# Can't encode to a JSONArray

Tags: php, arrays, json

About this question marked as duplicate, I wasn't asking about how to encode in the original question, the encoding was the answer to the question though.

In my php I've filled an array with data from a database (each object in the array is the row, stored as another array). I'm calling `echo json_encode($json);` so I can grab it through android but it doesn't output anything.
I can call each array and every column like `echo $json[#][#];` and get the expected result, so I know the arrays are filled.
How do I get it all out there so people can touch it with their greedy little fingers?

php:

```
<?php
    $host="HOST";
    $username="USER";
    $password="PASS";
    $db_name="DATABASE";

    $con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $json[] = array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5'], $row['col6']);
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
?>
```

***SOLVED***
The problem was with UTF8, on some columns that have text, occasionally specail characters are used (in this case, Å, Ä and Ö).
Thanks to commenter @meda that suggested I use `utf8_encode($row[col])` everything's fine.

Comment: can you print_r your result here

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, added the php in the question

Comment: Use print_r json_encode($json);

Comment: `How do I get it all out there so people can touch it with their greedy little fingers?` what does this mean bro

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, I get the same result (nothing)

Comment: @meda, I need it to work so my app (used by people with greedy fingers) can retrieve data. Bro.

Comment: sorry I didnt get the joke, still wanna help out though

Comment: Maybe some charset issue? json_encode only works with UTF-8 afaik. What does json_encode return? "Nothing" is not specific enough - null, false, empty string?

Comment: what you get from $row['col1'] ? JSON array or JSON object?

Comment: See `echo json_last_error_msg()`.

Comment: @Hirnhamster, it was the UTF-8, I removed the entries with "special characters" and now it works. There must be a way to make it send "special characters"? It's useless otherwise

Comment: `utf8_encode($row['col1'])`

Comment: Converting your input to UTF-8 should do the trick. See [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) for example

Comment: @meda, thanks that works! I only have two columns where this could happen so that works really well.